# how to give file uri in build envelope method of android sdk

Tags: android, docusignapi

I am trying to access pdf file from android phone in build envelope method of android sdk as

```
.uri("file:///storage/emulated/0/FileExplorer/")
.name("12_24_2020")
```

but its giving me error `Invalid json` and in logcat error as

```
2020-12-25 15:55:35.946 9439-9439/com.example.docusignapp E/main: 
Unknown exception in loading document: 
File is not a valid, parseable, password-free PDF.
```

My file is not password protected.

Kindly help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [SDK docs](https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk#envelope-creation) show the `.uri` parameter as the path to a specific file.

I suggest you try a specific file, not a file explorer.